# How to filter rows if contain specific string variable "word"

Tags: stata

I have data in Stata coding info in string words. I need to filter the rows if any variable is named "R45851" if not I do not need the whole row
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QvWf.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is about finding observations (rows, in spreadsheet jargon) with a value (**not** a name) within one or more variables. One recipe is

```
gen found = 0 

foreach v of var I* { 
    replace found = (`v' == "R45851") if !found
} 

list if found
```

If the *varlist* (here `I*`) contains numeric variables, filter first, or put `capture` in front of the `replace`.

Comment: Can I filter the data if the row contain this value or not?

Comment: Yes; that is what `found` lets you do -- and the `list` command is an example.